# How linkedlist.removeIf works in this case

Tags: java, list, linked-list, collectors, collect

First I create a simple list of 6 items.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);

    LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    System.out.println("Введите числа списка: ");
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        String s = reader.readLine();
        linkedList.add(s);
    }
```

According to the task, I need to remove from the list the elements whose values have already been encountered in previous elements.

```
linkedList.removeIf(
            s ->linkedList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())).get(s) == 2);
```

I understand what collect does. But how is the grouping going? And it is unclear what ==2 has to do with it after get(s).
As far as I understand, we are grouping by the value of the input argument (element) and by the amount of this value in the list. We get it using get(s). But how does ==2 work?

Comment: It seems, that you have multiple questions. Try to be more focused in your questions.

Comment: [groupingBy][https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-] creates a map whose key is in this case the identity of the value, so if your s is "3" then the key is "3" as well. And the Value of each entry will be the amount of occurrences of for example "3".

Comment: The `== 2` relates to the predicate given to the `removeIf` method. So, the entry "s" is getting removed if, its amount of occurrences in the map resulting from the groupingBy is equal to 2 it will be removed.

Comment: The evaluation of `linkedList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())` should be extracted to its own variable before constructing it for every value when iterating it inside the removeIf.

Comment: @ValerijDobler like that? Map<String, Long> collector = linkedList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

Comment: Yes, maybe call it something more meaningful like `amountOfOccurences`

Comment: @ValerijDobler I did, but the output is empty.

Comment: Comparing the count with `2` will match when there are *exactly* two occurrences. It will not match when a value occurs three times, for example. Further, `removeIf` will remove *all* occurrences of matching elements, rather than keeping the first. And the approach is very inefficient. Change `LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();` to `LinkedHashSet<String> linkedList = new LinkedHashSet<>();` and it will prevent duplicates from being added in the first place, without the need for fixing afterwards. Then, rename `linkedList` to, e.g. `lines`, reflecting the purpose, not the type.